# Reconfigure On Premise Data Gateway desktop app

Tags: azure, data-gateway

I have by mistake configured my on premise data gateway to point to a wrong data center. Now I am unable to reconfigure the gateway desktop app. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the data gateway. But as soon as I login to the desktop app it picks up the old config. I do not see an option in the app reconfigure it. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Tiklu

Comment: Is this the Azure Data Factory gateway? PowerBI? can you give more detail.

Comment: This is the data gateway for PowerBI/Logic Apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did posted the same query in the Microsoft forum and got the answer for the same. The link is as bellow

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/900374fe-9249-41f0-9674-a4c32a882ccc/reconfigure-on-premise-data-gateway-desktop-app?forum=azurelogicapps

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to go on app.powerbi.com, settings and manage gateways. From there you can remove/add gateways with full server identification and target of the gateways.